# Flutter error - Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm working on a Flutter Application Project.
For a few days I have an issue when running my application. To test it, I create another project but issue is still present.

I have this exception : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

[Issue part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rOyr.png)
[Issue part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJbhe.png)

If someone has already encountered this problem or has any idea how to solve it i am really interested.

Thanks in advance.

----- UPDATE ----

My issue came from antivirus program which removed my sdkmanager.bat.
When I was doing "flutter doctor", the license was always "not accepted" and after the command "flutter doctor --android-licenses" the sdkmanager was not found.

Solution

On Windows :

do the command Windows + R

Search msconfig

Go to Services

Hide Windows Services

And find this famous antivirus

To finish, reinstall sdk tools (I have the sdk command line tools (obsolete))

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `main.dart` file and any other subsequent Widgets that you call from the `main.dart` file.

Comment: It's not related to my code but rather in relation to the configuration. I have the same error with when I start from a new project

Comment: Can you share the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: I published below the result of flutter doctor command

Answer (score 0):

In flutter you can generate APK using this command inside your app directory:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

This will generate 3 apks for different architecture

Comment: Hello, after this command i still have the issue Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before. This happened to me because terms and conditions that you must accept. First, go to the terminal and run

> flutter doctor

It should then show you that you have not accepted the terms, and ask you if you want to accept them now. Follow the instructions on screen and accept each one, there will be around 7. After that relaunch your IDE and it should run fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To reply to your answer @Landon Stahl, I haven't issue when I order flutter doctor

[Before try to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JuCX.png)

And after try to run app I have : "Android license status unknown"

[after try to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG6xT.png)

Comment: License status doesn't matter much. I have a few recommendations as you're a beginner. 1. You can edit your question to add extra information, don't post an answer for that. 2. Don't post images of the text/code but copy the text/code and paste it here.

Comment: Ok thanks for informations.
Do you have other ideas to my issue ? I'm desperately looking for the solution, I uninstalled Android Studio, using other IDE, I have reinstalled Flutter but without success